# How to fix 'Key Error: Index' error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am building a neural network model. I am using Jupyter Notebook and I have imported the necessary libraries. There are two datasets and it is merged into one. After merging when I run **this code**, KeyError: Index([ ]) error message displays. Can you please help me to solve the issue.

**The code:**

```
merge_vector = ["school","sex","age","address",
                "famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu",
                "Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"]

duplicated_mask = merged_df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=merge_vector)
```

**Error message:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-4f1a3ab8858b> in <module>()
----> 1 duplicated_mask = merged_df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=merge_vector)

E:\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   4379         diff = Index(subset).difference(self.columns)
   4380         if not diff.empty:
-> 4381             raise KeyError(diff)
   4382 
   4383         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.iteritems()

KeyError: Index(['Fedu', 'Fjob', 'Medu', 'Mjob', 'Pstatus', 'address', 'age', 'famsize',
       'internet', 'nursery', 'reason', 'school', 'sex'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Imported libraries for the NN model**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from math import floor, ceil
from pylab import rcParams

%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) columns names with `merge_vector`, because in DataFrame some columns not exist:

```
merge_vector = ["school","sex","age","address",
                "famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu",
                "Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"]

merged_df = pd.DataFrame({'internet':[4,5,5],
                          'school':[7,8,8],
                          'new':[1,2,3]})
print (merged_df)
   internet  school  new
0         4       7    1
1         5       8    2
2         5       8    3

existed_cols = merged_df.columns.intersection(merge_vector)
print (existed_cols)
Index(['internet', 'school'], dtype='object')

duplicated_mask = merged_df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=existed_cols)
print (duplicated_mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. The first line worked but after executing the ````duplicated_mask = merged_df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=existed_cols) ```` line a value error message shows telling ````ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)````

Comment: @Kaawya - It means there are no columns from `existed_cols` like `merged_df = pd.DataFrame({'internetw':[4,5,5],
                          'ss':[7,8,8],
                          'dd':[1,2,3]})`, so test your real columns names  by `print (merged_df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: It worked!! I first didn't understand what you meant because I didn't check your reply completely. I'm a newbie so it took some time for me to figure it out. Thank you so much!!!! - @jezrael